# Preferred serialization method for simple VB project

Tags: vb.net, serialization

This is newbie VB question.
 My son is learning VB and I am learning with him. We have RichEdit control application (non WPF), where we input text, formatting its Style (bold, italic, underline, etc.).
  Our next task is to save the text together with its attributes into the file. 
 The question is: what type of serialization is preferred at this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Serialisation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx) probably isn't what you want in this instance.

I'd just save the RTF text directly to a file. e.g.

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\\MyRTFDocument.rtf", rtftextBox.Rtf);
```

You can then open the file in any RTF editor (e.g. MS Word)

To read the file contents again

```
rtftextBox.Rtf = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\MyRTFDocument.rtf");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Or alternatively use the LoadFile & SaveFile methods (in Hans' answer) that I was un-aware of (you can unselect my answer as the correct answer and pick the answer by [Hans Passant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10985238/18797)), it is _more_ correct, in that it uses built in functions which may be optimised by the control to more effeciently write the data to the file. Always (for a given value of always) use functionality exposed by components rather than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what a "RichEdit control" might be, assuming you are talking about the RichTextBox control.  You should highly prefer the serialization already implemented by RichTextBox.  Use its LoadFile and SaveFile methods.

Comment: +1. Here's the documentation for WinForms RichTextBox [LoadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f99sst7) and [SaveFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bf5hy2e). The file format is RTF.

Comment: +1: I was unaware of LoadFile & SaveFile, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) supports a wide range of object graphs, and has the additional learning benefit of serializing to XML format so that the serialized data can be inspected.